# Android: Orientation change start intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, screen-orientation

Is it possible to start an intent when the phone goes from portrait to landscape mode and vice versa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Add the following to the activity declaration in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

so it looks like

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:name=".your.package">
```

Write the code to whatever you want in `onConfigurationChanged()` method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    //write your logic here
    System.out.println("...inside config change...");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: One should keep in mind that this method has disadvantages. Namely, it becomes more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system stops to manage them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to implement the [`OrientationEventListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) and load the Intent on `onOrientationChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a static field in your Activity and check the current orientation in `onCreate()` using [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html). If the field is empty, store the configuration, if it's not, check for changes, take the necessary actions and store the new configuration afterwards.